# How does RStudio determine the console width, and why does it seem to be getting it consistently wrong?

Tags: r, rstudio

I just discovered `wid <- options()$width` in RStudio, and it seems to be the source (or rather, much closer to the source) of much irritation in my everyday console usage. I should say up front that I'm currently on R 3.2.2, RStudio 0.99.491, on Linux Mint 17.3 (built over Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS)

As I understand it, `wid` should be measured in characters -- if `wid` is equal to 52, say, then one should be able to fit the alphabet on the screen twice (given the fixed-width default font), but this doesn't appear to be the case:

[image: A screenshot showing the observed-vs-actual width discrepancy. The first line shows a call to options()$width and its output (52); the second line types out the alphabet twice, but the second time only makes it to 't' (if the true width was 52, the second alphabet should complete)]

As you can see, despite having `wid` equal to 52, I am unable to fit the alphabet twice -- I come up 6 characters short. I also note that this means it is *not* simply due to the presence of the command prompt arrow and space (`>` ).

The problem seems somewhat proportional -- if I have `wid` up to 78, I can only fit 70 characters; up to 104, 93, so `wid` is about 88% off pretty consistently (side note: this also suggests my assumption `wid` is measured in characters is probably right).

The problem that this engenders is that oftentimes console output overflows beyond its intended line, making the output ugly and hard to digest; take, for example, the simple snipped `setDT(lapply(1:30, function(x) 1:3))[]` which produces for me:

[image: A screenshot of garbled output. A 3-row, 27-colum data.table is printed, but columns 26 and 27 interweave with the other columns, instead of being put alongside the next register of output where columns 28-30 ended up.]

It seems clear to me that the output was attempted on a screen width which was not available in practice -- that internally, a larger screen width than actually exists was used for printing.

This leaves me with three questions:

1. How is `options()$width` determined?
2. Why is it so consistently wrong?
3. What can we do to override this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a [post about this on Rstudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202648023--width-option-not-detected-correctly) and it seems the issue has to do with high DPI Displays; there is a claimed bug fix in [RStudio version 0.99.878](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) (released just today! as luck would have it), according to the [release notes](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/release-notes/):

> ## Bug Fixes
>
> ...
>
> - Correct computation of `getOption(“width”)` on high DPI displays

Hope this helps anyone else experiencing this! I'm tempted to post about this on [/r/oddlysatisfying](https://www.reddit.com/r/oddlysatisfying) B-)

Would love to see the relevant commit on the [RStudio GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio) page if anyone can track it down (I had no luck).