# wrap error messages for RStudio, preserving words

Tags: r, rstudio

What is the best way to text-wrap error messages (`message`, `warning`, `stop`) to avoid splitting words or filepaths?

```
long_message <- paste("Gee I'm really sorry but I couldn't find the file at",
                      "/usr/yourname/doc/misc/foo/bar/baz.txt because the directory",
                      "/usr/yourname/doc/misc/foo/bar/ doesn't exist.  Take a deep",
                      "breath, step away from the keyboard, do some relaxation",
                      "exercises, and try again."
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

- detect the console width (say it's 80 characters)
- if the message is at least 80 characters long, find the index of the whitespace character closest to 80 without going over
- replace that whitespace with `\n`
- start counting again from the `\n`, and repeat

Related question:  [How does RStudio determine the console width, and why does it seem to be getting it consistently wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283234/how-does-rstudio-determine-the-console-width-and-why-does-it-seem-to-be-getting)

Ideally I would like to avoid dependencies, as this function is for a package.

Comment: I self-answered this with a solution that does most of what I want, but I would rather not have the file paths broken across lines, in case someone wanted to cut and paste the file path.  In other words, `/` should not be considered an end-of-word character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or with {base} functions:

```
stop(paste(strwrap(long_message), collapse = "\n"))
```

Comment: Interesting, the base function doesn't treat `/` as a whitespace character, and keeps the entire filepath on the same line of the message.  This is what I want, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`stri_wrap` from the `stringi` package already does this, so by wrapping it in `paste(..., collapse = "\n")`, we can do:

```
message(paste(stringi::stri_wrap(long_message), collapse = "\n"))
```